# How can Spark take input after it is submitted

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I am designing an application, which requires response very fast and need to retrieve and process a large volume of data (>40G) from hadoop file system, given one input (command).

I am thinking, if it is possible to catch such high amount of data in the distributed memory using spark, and let the application running all the time. If I give the application an command, it could start to process data based on the input.

I think catching such big data is not a problem. However, how can I let the application running, and take input?

As far as I know, there is nothing can be done after "spark-submit" command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [spark job server](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver) and [Named Objects](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#using-named-objects) to cache dataset in distributed memory and use it in various input commands.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is not clear!!!, but based on my understanding,

1) In spark-submit after the application.jar, you can provide application specific command line arguments. But if you want to send commands after the job was started, then you can write a spark streaming job which processes kafka messages.

2) HDFS is already optimised for processing large volume of data. You can cache intermediate reusable data so that they do not get re-computed. But for better performance you might consider using something like elasticsearch/cassandra, so that they can be fetched/stored even faster.